# Pandas MultiIndex indexing does not work

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am exploring the MultiIndex, but for some reason the very basic indexing does not work for me.

The index:

```
In [119]: index
Out[119]: MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Group 1', u'Group 2'], [u'A01', u'A02', u'A03', u'A04']],
       labels=[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
       names=[u'Group', u'Well'])
```

The dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2), index=index)
```

The dataframe has the index:

```
In [124]: df.index
Out[124]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Group 1', u'Group 2'], [u'A01', u'A02', u'A03', u'A04']],
    labels=[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]],
    names=[u'Group', u'User'])
```

However indexing:

```
df['Group 1']
```

only results in an error

```
KeyError: 'Group 1'
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

To slice with index, you need `loc` for data frames as the [basic indexing with []](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basic) is meant to select columns; Since the data frame doesn't contain a column named `Group 1`, it raises a key error:

```
df.loc['Group 1']

#               0           1
#Well       
#A01    -0.337359   -0.113165
#A03     0.212714    1.619850
#A04     1.411829   -0.892723
```

---

Basic indexing table:

```
# Object Type         Selection        Return Value Type
#      Series     series[label]        scalar value
#   DataFrame    frame[colname]        Series corresponding to colname
#       Panel   panel[itemname]        DataFrame corresponding to the itemname
```

`loc` indexing table:

```
#Object Type    Indexers
#     Series    s.loc[indexer]
#  DataFrame    df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]
#      Panel    p.loc[item_indexer,major_indexer,minor_indexer]
```